# Lua - serialize functions without loadstring?

Tags: function, serialization, lua, storage

In lua, is it possible to serialize functions (without upvalues) and store them **WITHOUT USING LOADSTRING** ?

Comment: can you give a bit more info on what you're trying to do? do you mean serialize them in a way so that you don't need to use loadstring later? because you'd use string.dump to serialize the function.

Comment: I cannot use loadstring as my lua engine prevents its usage..  
So is it possible to store functions for a later use now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can serialize and store them without `loadstring` at all - use `string.dump`. You will only need `loadstring` if you want to deserealize them back.

If you need it to reuse actual function later, (and not for some other simple purpose, like comparing), you will still need access to at least string version of `loadstring`, because that's the only facility that allows you to evaluate Lua source on the fly.

If you have it, you may either try:
1) If you have access, modify Lua engine itself to save source code of function definition somewhere.
2) Write Lua bytecode to Lua source converter in Lua. With Lua's simple VM it is not as hard task as it may sound.

If you have absolutely no access to `loadstring` at all, you can try to write Lua VM in Lua. That'd be harder task than a simple converter, but still pretty doable.

Comment: Ah Well.. Thanks for the detailed answer!
Writing a VM is beyond me and not worth it for sure! 
Thanks anyway!